# RNGCryptoServiceProvider in .Net Core RRS feed

Tags: windows, .net-core

HI i am searching for highly Cryptographically secure random values, i need to use in .net core 2.2 framework

in microsoft saying  below two RNG's present in windows, i tried  using RNGCryptoServiceProvider it worked well.

1. Using RNGCryptoServiceProvider[edit]
   Programmers using .NET should use the RNGCryptoServiceProvider
2. Using Cryptography API: Next Generation (CNG)  is a long term replacement for the deprecated Crypto API. It provides an equivalent function BCryptGenRandom as well as dedicated functions for key generation.

Query Does RNGCryptoServiceProvider has its own algorithm in .net core or it uses BCryptGenRandom C++ calls internally ?

Please provide any links on this it will be helpful for me to know more.